# using thread safe local_time_r

Tags: c

I have the following c code, I would like to use the local_time_r which is thread safe, I get Segmentation fault, I don't know why.

```
time_t rawtime = 1441194527;
   struct tm *info;
   char buffer[80];

   time( &rawtime );

   info = localtime_r( &rawtime );

   strftime(buffer,80,"%Y-%m-%d %X", info);
   printf("Formatted date & time : |%s|\n", buffer );
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain the code that doesn't work, instead of the code that does work.

Comment: Your code isn't using `local_time_r` at all!

Comment: @Kerrek SB sorry it was a typo

Comment: Please edit your post also for your typos. Then, this is a good opportunity to learn how to use a debugger. He will tell you where your code segfaults and why.

Comment: Many compilers, when properly enabled, will provide useful warnings concerning incorrect function usage.  You can save time by insuring these warnings are enabled 1st and posting on SO 2nd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `localtime_r` is as follows:

```
struct tm *localtime_r(const time_t *timep, struct tm *result);
```

You need to pass it the address of a `struct tm`.  You don't want to pass `info` since it doesn't point anywhere, so change it to a non-pointer and pass its address.

```
time_t rawtime = 1441194527;
struct tm info;   // not a pointer
char buffer[80];

time( &rawtime );

localtime_r( &rawtime, &info );   // added parameter

strftime(buffer,80,"%Y-%m-%d %X", &info);   // changed parameter
printf("Formatted date & time : |%s|\n", buffer );
```